# How do I SELECT a MySQL Table value that has not been updated on a given date?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a MySQL database named mydb in which I store daily share prices for
423 companies in a table named data. Table data has the following columns:

```
`epic`, `date`, `open`, `high`, `low`, `close`, `volume`
```

`epic` and `date` being primary key pairs.
I update the data table each day using a csv file which would normally have 423 rows
of data all having the same date. However, on some days prices may not available
for all 423 companies and data for a particular epic and date pair will
not be updated. In order to determine the missing pair I have resorted
to comparing a full list of epics against the incomplete list of epics using
two simple SELECT queries with different dates and then using a file comparator, thus
revealing the missing epic(s). This is not a very satisfactory solution and so far
I have not been able to construct a query that would identify any epics that
have not been updated for any particular day.

```
SELECT `epic`, `date` FROM `data`
WHERE `date` IN ('2019-05-07', '2019-05-08')
ORDER BY `epic`, `date`;
```

Produces pairs of values:

```
`epic`  `date`
"3IN"   "2019-05-07"
"3IN"   "2019-05-08"
"888"   "2019-05-07"
"888"   "2019-05-08"
"AA."   "2019-05-07"
"AAL"   "2019-05-07"
"AAL"   "2019-05-08"
```

Where in this case AA. has not been updated on 2019-05-08. The problem with this is that it is not easy to spot a value that is not a pair.
Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `COUNT` on epic, with a `GROUP BY` epic for items in that date range and see if you get any with a `COUNT` less than 2, then select from this result where UpdateCount is less than 2, forgive me if the syntax on the column names is not correct, I work in SQL Server, but the logic for the query should still work for you.

```
SELECT x.epic
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS UpdateCount, epic
    FROM data
    WHERE date IN ('2019-05-07', '2019-05-08')
    GROUP BY epic
) AS x
WHERE x.UpdateCount < 2
```

Comment: @w2kpro What is the reason for this comment?

Comment: This produces the required result. SELECT COUNT(*) AS UpdateCount, `epic` FROM `data`
WHERE `date` IN ('2019-05-07', '2019-05-08')
GROUP BY `epic`
ORDER BY `UpdateCount` ASC;

Comment: @w2kpro That will return items where you got all updates, don't you just want to see the ones that didn't update on both days
?

Comment: an `epic` with value 1 comes to the top of the list and therefore has not been updated.

Comment: @w2kpro I understand that, that is how ORDER BY works, but  why do you want the ones which have all updates returned in the result set? I thought you only cared about viewing the ones without all updates, so by using what I gave you the only items in the result set will be ones which did not get updated on both days.

Comment: All I need is a method that identifies a missing value for a given update date. The above code produces a list of 443 values with the one of interest at the top of the list. I can't think of any other way to list the missing value directly on its own.

Comment: @w2kpro The query I gave you will return the epic value for only items which did not get all updates in the given time frame, I don't understand why this is not giving you what you need.

Comment: I must have somehow missed your second solution and have just run a test which returned the correct value of 'RNO'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to check the last date uploaded, the following will return every item not updated on 2019-05-08:

```
SELECT last_updated.epic, last_updated.date
FROM (
SELECT epic , max(`date`) AS date FROM `data`
GROUP BY 'epic'
) AS last_updated
WHERE 'date' <> '2019-05-08'
ORDER BY 'epic'
;
```

or for any upload date, the following will compare against the entire database, so you don't rely on '2019-08-07' having every epic row. I.e. if the epic has been in the database before then it will show if not updated:

```
SELECT d.epic, max(d.date)
FROM data as d
WHERE d.epic NOT IN (
   SELECT d2.epic 
   FROM data as d2 
   WHERE d2.date = '2019-05-08'
)
GROUP BY d.epic
ORDER BY d.epic
```

Comment: That didn't work. It produced a result of 3IN on '2019-05-09'. The correct result is `RNO` on '2019-05-08' which Ryan's code identifies

Comment: You would have to use the second option if you want to check a date that is not the latest date, because the first option finds the latest update and filters on this. I.e. the first option would work for your latest date, which I assume is '2019-05-09', but the second option should work for any date.

Comment: I have run a test with the latest update date being '2019-05-09' (443 values) and with the missing entry being 'RNO' on '2019-05-08' (442 values). The WHERE clause was set to <> '2019-05-08'. The result for your first query returned '3IN' '2019-05-09' and for your second query just one hit 'RNO'  '2019-05-08', which is the correct value.